# Can barcode scanning be achieved with just C# code in Blazor WASM, or is it necessary to use JSInterop and use a JS barcode library instead?

Tags: c#, .net-core, qr-code, blazor, webassembly

I am trying to implement a QR scanner in my Blazor PWA app to be used on mobile. Are there any libraries available for this?.

if there is no Blazor nuget library i am planning on using a javasccript library and use IJSRuntime.

please suggest.

Comment: Off Topic: Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more
This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.

Comment: You might want to change the wording of this question to something along the lines of 'Can barcode scanning be achieved with just C# code in Blazor WASM, or is it necessary to use JSInterop and use a JS barcode library instead?'.  That would get rid of the opinion based aspect of this question and stop it getting closed

Comment: The title is not long enough and only spans two lines.  Make it longer and go for 4

Answer (score 3):

I've used JsInterop with [QuaggaJS](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/) for a bar code scanner. Currently, I don't think that there is an available Nuget package for Blazor that can achieve this.

Comment: thanks i will try and do this. is there some code you can share?

Comment: Sry for a delayed answer. You can find my Github repo here: https://github.com/LorsSilvermort/BlazorBarcodeReader

Answer (score 0):

I've used this before and it worked wonderfully:

https://github.com/jackyef/rqrr-wasm